# AutoMapper Problem when creating mapping conditions with nullable value types in not-generic context

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, nullable

I am creating an AutoMapper functionality extension lib for my project and spotted a problem with Nullable value types. Here is a code I already wrote:

```cs
        public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> MapIfNotNullObj<TSource, TDestination>(
            this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> mapper,
            string destinationMember)
        {
            return mapper.ForMember(destinationMember, x => x.Condition(((source, destination, arg3, arg4) =>
            {
                bool condition = arg3 != null;
                
                Console.WriteLine("SOURCE: " + source);
                Console.WriteLine("DESTINATION: " + destination);
                Console.WriteLine("MEMBER SRC: " + arg3?.GetType().Name);
                Console.WriteLine("MEMBER DEST: " + arg4?.GetType().Name);
                Console.WriteLine("PASSED? " + condition);
                Console.WriteLine();
                return condition;
            })));
        }

        public static void CreateMapIfNotNull<TSource, TDestination>(
            this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> mapper)
        {
            foreach (var property in typeof(TDestination).GetProperties())
                MapIfNotNullObj(mapper, property.Name);
        }
```

For reference types it works correctly, but debug I made revealed me some interesting thing about how AutoMapper handles them. Here I provide example DTO's & simple test I wrote for my functionality: https://paste.mod.gg/axmcoaqxneei/0

Here are interesting (at least for me) debug lines for nullable value types:

```
SOURCE: Tests.AutoMapperTests+TestUserUpdateDto
DESTINATION: Tests.AutoMapperTests+TestUser
MEMBER SRC: Int32 ## THIS IS MEANT TO BE NULLABLE
MEMBER DEST: Int32
PASSED? True

SOURCE: Tests.AutoMapperTests+TestUserUpdateDto
DESTINATION: Tests.AutoMapperTests+TestUser
MEMBER SRC: Int32 ## THIS IS MEANT TO BE NULLABLE
MEMBER DEST: Int32
PASSED? True
```

So, it tells me that AutoMapper completely disregards value type's nullability and just uses base default types on map, which makes me trouble, because sometimes in my app default value is an expected one.

(Edit: I have also debugged values of the args -> For not-null property it was alright, for null value - 0)

My question is, how can I detect if the source property is a nullable value type, and only if it's not null, update destination type (reminder: default values are sometimes expected)?

Edit 2:

Thanks for your answer, but as I said - my circumsnatnces are different than those you provided. Check my MapIfNotNullObj method - it does not take Expression with proper member, but only destination member name. I only have access to raw `object`'s.

Plus, I did some research on AutoMapper's source code, and found that class which pretty well explains me AM's beavior with nullable types: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/NullableSourceMapper.cs . TLDR: That class directly takes Nullable value instead of checking if it's null.

So, that's why my debug methods are showing me Int32 instead of Nullable. And in this case, my question changes a little bit - How can I detect in `x.Condition((src, dest, srcMem, destMem) => {})` that source type is actually a nullable value type & if it's actually null?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've ran across a similar issue with a DTO mapping onto an existing entity model. The solution I think I used was something along the lines of:

Mapping

```
CreateMap<TestUserUpdateDto, TestUser>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom<IntNullAndDefaultResolver, int?>(src => src.Id));
```

Resolver

```
public class IntNullAndDefaultResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, int?, int>
{
    public int Resolve(object source, object destination, int? sourceMember, int destinationMember, ResolutionContext context) =>
        sourceMember.HasValue &&
        sourceMember.Value != default
            ? sourceMember.Value
            : destinationMember;
}
```